# Writing Large File To Disk Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, large-files, streamwriter

I am attempting to write and then read a large random file to calculate disk speed. I have tried several algorithms but keep getting an out or memory exception when attempting to write a 1GB file. Here are a few I have tried

Method 1

```
   byte[] data = new byte[8192];
        Random rng = new Random();
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fileSizeMb * 128; i++)
            {
                rng.NextBytes(data);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
```

Method 2

```
const int blockSize = 1024 * 8;
            const int blocksPerMb = (1024 * 1024) / blockSize;

            int count = fileSizeMb * blocksPerMb;

            byte[] data = new byte[blockSize];
            Random rng = new Random();
            //using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
            using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                // There 
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    rng.NextBytes(data);
                    sw1.BaseStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    //stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                }
            }
```

Reading

```
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting `OutOfMemoryException` when **reading**? And btw, `StreamReader/Writer` are for reading/wrinting text data, for binary data use just `Stream`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method 1

```
        byte[] data = new byte[8192];
        Random rng = new Random();
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fileSizeMb * 128; i++)
            {
                rng.NextBytes(data);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Flush(); // BEETLE JUICE
            }
        }
```

Method 2

```
        const int blockSize = 1024 * 8;
        const int blocksPerMb = (1024 * 1024) / blockSize;

        int count = fileSizeMb * blocksPerMb;

        byte[] data = new byte[blockSize];
        Random rng = new Random();
        using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            // There 
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                rng.NextBytes(data);
                sw1.BaseStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                sw1.baseStream.Flush(); // BEETLE JUICE
            }
        }
```

Reading

Do not read the whole file into memory, just read 4096 bytes at a time. Sample code at http://www.csharp-examples.net/filestream-read-file/